# Tab Bar, pop to root view controller(default vc) when coming from another tab's view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

Okay. It seems pretty easy for some of you guys but I have been facing this issue since very long.

My problem is this:

--> I have 5 tab bar controllers each consisting navigation controllers.

--> Now I have multiple view controllers attached to each tab bar controller like this:

> Tab1 -- VCa -> VCb -> VCc
>
> Tab2 -- VCd -> VCe -> VCf
>
> Tab3 -- VCg -> VCh -> VCi
>
> Tab4 -- VCj -> VCk -> VCl
>
> Tab5 -- VCm -> VCn -> VCo

--> When I launch My app and select **Tab2**, then I navigate to **VCd -> VCe -> VCf**

--> Now I select **Tab5**, then I navigate to **VCm -> VCn** and here I have a button that navigates me back to **Tab2**.

> Tab5, On a button click in VCn

```
self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1 // Navigate back to Tab2
```

--> Now here is the issue. I am navigated to **Tab2(VCf)** successfully. But My problem is that I wish to show default(first/initial) **Tab2(VCd)**.

So how can I go with it?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in anticipation. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
guard let controllers = tabBarController?.viewControllers, 
      let controller = controllers[1] as? UINavigationController else { return }
controller.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can change the root view controllers for each tab using `setViewControllers`.

So something like,

```
let rootViewControllers = [VCa, VCd, VCg, VCj, VCm]
self.tabBarController.setViewControllers(rootViewControllers, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this is to reach into the navigation stack, grab the UINavigationController inside tab 2, and make it pop back to the root view.

```
self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1 
(self.tabBarController?.viewControllers[1] as? UINavigationController)?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
```

Note however, that this might fail if you ever change the navigation structure.